# How to include a sub-script in a remote shell from remote location?

Tags: macos, bash, ubuntu-14.04

I am running a local bootstrap.sh script from OSX on a remote Ubuntu server which does some "if else then" stuff to load a specific subscript.sh when a specific condition is met.

I am running that local script with:

```
ssh user@host "bash -s" <~/projects/projectname/bootstrap.sh
```

I am having issues with getting the subscript.sh sourced (loaded/included).

Comment: if you're a complete newbie to shell scripting, this is not the project to learn on. I have some experience with running shell scripts from a local machine on a remote machine by embedding them in the `ssh` command string, but I don't see how what you're asking to do is possible. You can send all of the scripts 'over the wire' (with a lot of "opportunities" for debugging problems and fragilness.) OR you can copy fresh files from your local to the remote:/tmp and run everything there, which is the approach I would recommend to you. Good luck.

Comment: IMHO it looks it isn't **more easy** ... Simply, you can't do this easy. The `bash` is running on the rmeote machine and simple has no knowledge about your filesystem.

Comment: You don't really need to copy any script files over the wire if you can rewrite the commands within a function. You can then send the function over the wire and execute the function remotely.

Comment: thx, can you provide a sample how I could achieve to get the path to the source just looking in the same folder as it's "parent" or do I always need a full path / variable to full path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You're only sending the contents of `bootstrap.sh` to the remote shell. It's attempting to source `subscript.sh` on the remote machine, and it isn't there.

You'll need to either copy `subscript.sh` (or both scripts!) to the remote machine, or insert the contents of `subscript.sh` into `bootstrap.sh` in place of the `source` command.

Comment: sounds like bad news for me :(

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is to rsync your 'bootstrap.sh' from your local computer to your server. You should be able to do this with your ssh credentials.

A very cool utility is Transmit. It is $25 and allows you to cleanly mount your server as if it were a portable hard drive (Transmit can also do synchronizations). All you need is ssh credentials and is very user friendly.

If you are allowed to install on your server, then I would install qsub on it. (Actually just check to see if it is installed.) Then just mount your computer's drive and you can submit scrips with qsub (I actually would just make a small server on your mac). This is what I use for using a linux cluster from my OSX computer.

Alternatively you can make a small server from your osx and have it mounted on your linux server.